# adding typescript to a node project in visual studio 2013

Tags: node.js, typescript, webstorm

I had just installed the new node extension on visual studio 2013 and  created the default express project which has:

this app.js:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

but when I try to add a ts file I don't see the option,

any ideas what I need to do next to properly allow typescript support.

Maybe I should switch to webstorm but I don't know if it will handle the node stuff as good as the node extension for VS2013

Answer (score 0):

You also need to install the TypeScript extension for Visual Studio 2013.

You can download it from http://typescriptlang.org

Or directly from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=266563

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the TEAN project,

This is a Typescript + ExpressJS + Angular + NodeJS quickstart

https://github.com/urigoren/TEAN/